# Is it possible to forward an SMS?

Tags: sms

In the UK, [individuals are advised](http://www.ico.gov.uk/for_the_public/topic_specific_guides/marketing/texts.aspx) to forward unsolicited SMS messages to 7726 (or, on vodafone, 87726). Is it possible to forward an SMS using a Windows Phone device? if so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can press on the 'cloud' with the text (or any message) and hold a moment. Then, the option 'forward' appears. I suppose you will know what to do next.